# Lubuntu on top of Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

If I install lubuntu "on top of ubuntu", do I really get the low overhead effect of lubuntu as if I installed a lubuntu iso?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

What you mean is installing the `lubuntu-desktop` meta-package on top of your Ubuntu installation.

In fact, Lubuntu (and all Ubuntu flavors) is built on top of the exact same base used in Ubuntu. The only thing that changes is the **desktop environment** and the **default applications**.

A meta-package is a group of packages which are installed together as part of something bigger. The meta-package `lubuntu-desktop` brings the LXDE desktop along with applications like Abiword, Gnumeric, Firefox, etc. If you install it on top of the Unity desktop you'll basically have the full functionalities of **both Ubuntu and Lubuntu at the same time**, and LXDE's performance should be just the same as in a pure Lubuntu install.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  One other question i posted (not answered) was on a ubuntu clicking noise I have on my solid state acer 131t-c1yf.  I highly suspect it is the graphics cherryview.  If I use an old 13.04 lubuntu usb,  I do not get the noise.  If I use a Mint17  usb, I get a warning that the graphics card is not being used, and then the clicking stops after that message.  15.10 ubuntu clicks and it clicks with the Lubuntu basic desktop desktop shell. (Not the whole thing).  I am an American monk in Myanmar and downloading 1gb is a project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience about your problem. It surely deserves opening a new question. You'll have my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just made a usb of Lubuntu.  There is a huge difference and no clicking noise.

**Memory on Lubuntu (pure by usb) is 222 mb.**
About **half** of lubuntu on top of ubuntu..  ie. Ubuntu is installed and the Lubuntu desktop shell is installed after the fact and chosen on login.

No clicking noise which is my biggest worry.

Looks like I will likely be removing ubuntu soon, mostly because the clicking noise is unanswered and worries me.

I really like Ubuntu after installing Gnome and Lubuntu on my Ubuntu system.  I hope this gets fixed.  I hope the ideas of shells consuming the proper resources is also fixed.